# In Ruby on Rails, how do I make a polymorphic model associate to a namespaced model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models.

```
# app/models/domain/domain_object.rb
class Domain::DomainObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links_from, :class_name => "Link", :as => :from, :dependent => :destroy
end

# app/models/link.rb
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from, :polymorphic => true 
  belongs_to :object_value, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Problem is, when I do the following, the from_type doesn't prefix the Domain namespace to the model e.g.

```
 Domain::DomainObject.all(:include=> :links_from )
```

That causes the following SELECT:

```
 SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (`links`.`from_id` IN (5,6,12,13,18,24,25,27,29,30,31,32,34,35,39) and `links`.`from_type` = 'DomainObject')
```

The query should be:

```
 SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (`links`.`from_id` IN (5,6,12,13,18,24,25,27,29,30,31,32,34,35,39) and `links`.`from_type` = 'Domain::DomainObject')
```

because Rails automatically saves the model with the namespace.

I've seen a few recommendations on Rails sites about doing something like this:

```
   belongs_to :from, :polymorphic => true, :class_name => "Domain::DomainObject"
```

However, that doesn't appear to work either.

So, is there a better way to do this?  Or is this not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this, I did a `include Domain` in the `DomainObject` model and set `ActiveRecord::Base.store_full_sti_class = true` in `config/environment.rb`.

Answer (score 3):

hoyhoy's response is the solution. This solved my problem , too (I actually wanted the namespace to be stripped off).

However, I'd recommend that `x.store_full_sti_class = true` be added to `config/environment.rb`, only if it is desired globally. I imagine it might not always be required, in which case, we can easily translate the solution to the class level.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.store_full_sti_class = true
  ...
end
```